# To state whether the given function is entire or not

Tags: complex-analysis

Is function $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{e^z-1} \forall z \in C$ entire?
I know the singularities are infinite on imaginary axis given as $z=2π n i$. 
A function is said to be entire if it is analytic over the entire complex plane. So according to the definition $f$ is not entire.

But there is a theorem that states
"If $f$ is a continuous mapping from $C$ to $C$ such that $f$ is analytic except $[-1,1]$ then $f$ is entire function"

So if I refer this $f$ should be entire (if I am not wrong)

Also I need to prove the above theorem.

How shall I proceed this?

Comment: Check out $ z = 0$.

Comment: Yes I got it. That means function is not entire both way.

Comment: Indeed! Go ahead, and answer the question so it can be closed. :)

Comment: I also want to prove the theorem. "If $f$ is a continuous mapping from $C$ to $C$ such that $f$ is analytic except $[-1,1]$ then $f$ is entire function"Anyone here who is going to help me for this?

Comment: I think if you post that as a separate question, you'll find people happy to help you with it.